# How to configure SlideView in App.XAML for wp8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have been struggling to add facebook like slide view in my app.XAML page. Though there isn't enough documentation about this. I would appreciate your advice on the issue.
My App.XAML

```
 <Application
    x:Class="DuaAndAzkar.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:DuaAndAzkar"
    xmlns:library="using:SlideView.Library" >

    <library:SlideApplicationFrame>
        <library:SlideApplicationFrame.LeftContent>
            <pages:LeftView />
        </library:SlideApplicationFrame.LeftContent>
    </library:SlideApplicationFrame>

</Application>
```

I am getting a lot of error message, but the one I know is pages prefix which is in the app.XAML page and this is the root of the error. The exact error message is

> The namespace prefix "pages" is not defined

So How can I have my App.XAML having the facebook like slideview?

Comment: That component is using FlipView if I'm not mistaken and it's buggy.  Look at a snippet I posted on git https://github.com/fillobotto/DoubleSidebarMenu

Comment: I am looking for something known as a Humberger style layout.

Comment: Look at my solution, it's perfect

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the pages namespace in which you actually defined the views needed for the left and right views. It would probably be in a folder under your app project, something like this.

```
xmlns:pages="using:DuaAndAzkar.Pages"
```

That Pages namespace should have your LeftView and RightView pages defined.

Check out the [sample on CodePlex](https://slideview.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Trunk/SlidingPanel/SlideView.Sample.WP81/Pages/Shell/LeftView.xaml), it shows in details how to use this control.